# pandas get one or other column alternative to np.where

Tags: pandas

imagine i have a dataframe like this

```
exDF=pd.DataFrame({'choice':['left','right','left','left','right'],'LeftDoor':['l1','l2','l3','l4','l5'],'RightDoor':['r1','r2','r3','r4','r5']})


    choice  LeftDoor RightDoor
   0    left    l1   r1
   1    right   l2   r2
   2    left    l3   r3
   3    left    l4   r4
   4    right   l5   r5
```

I want to get the choice that was made, e.g. either the value from LeftDoor or RightDoor as efficiently as possible.

For example, I tried

```
chosen=np.where(exDF['choice']=='left',exDF['LeftDoor'],exDF['RightDoor'])
not_chosen=np.where(exDF['choice']=='left',exDF['RightDoor'],exDF['LefttDoor'])
```

but this seems very inefficient, and in fact takes a very long time with a big dataframe

The other option could be

```
chosenLeft=exDF['choice']=='left'
chosenRight=exDF['choice']=='Right'
```

but then how do I combine these two into one column that lists 'chosen'. The different indexes don't align with `pd.concat()`

Basically I want to get an out with 2 columns

```
chosen:[l1,r2,l3,l4,r5]
not_chosen:[r1,L2,r3,r4,l5]
```

I may be overcomplicating this, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think `np.where` is fastest here:

```
#500k rows
exDF = pd.concat([exDF] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

In [55]: %%timeit
    ...: m = exDF['choice']=='left'
    ...: chosen=np.where(m,exDF['LeftDoor'],exDF['RightDoor'])
    ...: not_chosen=np.where(m,exDF['RightDoor'],exDF['LeftDoor'])
    ...: 
32.4 ms ± 216 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [56]: %%timeit
    ...: m = exDF['choice']=='left'
    ...: chosen=exDF['LeftDoor'].where(m,exDF['RightDoor'])
    ...: not_chosen=exDF['RightDoor'].where(m,exDF['LeftDoor'])
    ...: 
55.8 ms ± 223 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```